# Chaining aggreggation procedures

Tags: python, aggregation, chaining

I have the following code:

```
myData_agg = myData.groupby("Customer")["PurchAmount"].sum()
myData_agg.loc[myData_agg>=100,]
```

Can I write this code in one procedure? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

*Option one:*

Chain them with `[]` and a `lambda` expression:

```
myData.groupby("Customer")["PurchAmount"].sum()[lambda x: x >= 100]
```

*Option two:*

Use the `compress` method:

```
myData.groupby("Customer")["PurchAmount"].sum().compress(lambda x: x >= 100)
```

*Option three:*

Use `pipe`:

```
myData.groupby("Customer")["PurchAmount"].sum().pipe(lambda x: x[x >= 100])
```